# Trying to mount ddrescue image from a 1tb crashed ntfs drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, dd

It was time, after 5 years my 1tb external drive with all of my family photos and all my music crashed.
Stupidly enough, i did not have two drives in raid, which i will do in the future.

I successfully rescued the files with dd_rescue to my other 2tb movie drive on my server, however i cannot seem to understand how to mount this .img file.

I am using GNU ddrescue

I really need to get this fixed, otherwise i'm screwed

Here's how i have executed my ddrescue command

> sudo ddrescue /dev/sdh1 /media/external/rescue/rescue.img /media/external/rescue/rescuelog

```
Initial status (read from logfile)
rescued:        1 TB,  errsize:  30944 kB,  errors:     345
Finished
```

Here are my test commands

> file image.img

```
image.img: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x52, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, reserved sectors 0, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80)
```

> fdisk -l image.img

```
Disk image.img: 1000.2 GB, 1000203091968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953521664 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
image.img1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
image.img2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
image.img3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
image.img4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

I have absolutely no idea why fdisk shows all these wierd partitions such as 'DiskSecure Multi-Boot' and two 'Unknown' partitions, the parted command gave me information that seemed correct though

> parted image.img print

```
WARNING: You are not superuser.  Watch out for permissions.
Model:  (file)
Disk /media/external/Rescue/image.img: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1000GB  1000GB  ntfs
```

I am not sure if i have the correct flags and such, but here i'm trying to mount the drive

> sudo mount -r -o loop image.img /mnt

```
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Index buffer (VCN 0x0) of directory inode 0x5 has a size (24) differing from the directory specified size (4096).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Index buffer (VCN 0x0) of directory inode 0x5 has a size (24) differing from the directory specified size (4096).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Index buffer (VCN 0x0) of directory inode 0x5 has a size (24) differing from the directory specified size (4096).
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I can only see warnings. You don't seem to get any errors while mounting. Maybe it mounted just fine? Do you see anything if you do a `ls /mnt` ?

Comment: ls gives me `ls: reading directory /mnt: Input/output error`

Comment: Ah, right. You've rescued the whole drive and now the image contains multiple partitions. You will only want to mount one partition at the time. Never did this myself, but try this from [this article](http://depletionmode.com/2010/07/29/mounting-an-image-with-multiple-partitions/): `mount -t ntfs -o loop,offset=1953251627 image.img /mnt` if that doesn't work you will need to cut out the partition following [this article](http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux).

Comment: It was a single NTFS partition before, are you saying that ddrescue splitted it up?
And is it multiple partitions or not? Since fdisk tells me there are 4 partitions while parted info tells me that it is just a single partition, and in that article you linked they use parted info.
Your command gives me `NTFS signature is missing.`, and since parted told me that it started at the 0 byte, i also tried offset 0 but it gave me same error as the `sudo mount -r -o loop image.img /mnt` in the OP but only once instead of for times

Answer (score 2):

Your partition table is corrupted, you have to use windows and run `chkdsk /f` on that corrupted image file. Check [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/615683/perform-a-chkdsk-on-an-ntfs-image) for some instructions.

Comment: I'll install windows 7 on my machine and try to do that. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, this was not possible. When running chkdsk it gave me the error "Insufficient disk space to fix volume bitmap. CHKDSK aborted.", and according to microsofts website about this error message: "Delete some unneeded files from the NTFS volume, if you can, and then retry the Chkdsk command. If you cannot delete any files, you will have to reformat the NTFS volume and restore data from backup.".

Since i'm not able to free space from the image i have no idea what to do. And only 400gb of the 1tb was used anyway, so the error message doesn't make any sense really.

Comment: @JohanBjäreholt I don't use Windows, and this is a windows problem, you will likely have better answers on http://superuser.com/ . But a little googling for that error suggests that `chkdsk` reports that problem also when there is enough free space, it is basically a sign of a very big, unrecoverable corruption. But as I said, I don't use/know windows, so I can't really help you with that problem.